# How can i modify my UploadFiles Task to receive all of file types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Here is my Task

```
private async Task UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs inputFileChangeEventArgs)
    {
        _CarregaFoto = true;

        var fileFormat = "image/png";

        var MAXALLOWEDSIZE = 60000000;

        var imageFile = await inputFileChangeEventArgs.File.RequestImageFileAsync(fileFormat, 6000, 6000);

        var buffer = new byte[imageFile.Size];

        await imageFile.OpenReadStream(MAXALLOWEDSIZE).ReadAsync(buffer);

        AnexoDenunciaModel _novaFoto = new AnexoDenunciaModel();

        _novaFoto.imagem = buffer;
        _novaFoto.id_ocorre = id;
        _novaFoto.nome = imageFile.Name;
        _novaFoto.Denunciante = true;

        await _db.InsertAnexoDenuncia(_novaFoto);

        _CarregaFoto = false;

        await LeTabelas2();

    }
```

I've tried to change var fileFormat to pdf or discart this part but with no success, the task only accept png, jpg, etc. files. How can i accept other types like pdf, txt files?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server

```
    private int maxAllowedFiles = 3;
    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
        {
               DO YOUR STUFF
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've already tried this, but only solve the problem to access multiple files at a time, the data type problem still remain.

Comment: @ThiagoFontoura, Perhaps you could share more of your code?  Also, perhaps you can edit it so that only the important bits are there? I'm fairly certain you're not concerned with the part that saves your files to the database.  Also, this appears to be the server side code. What does your client side code look like?  You've only painted a partial picture of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor does not limit you on the possible filetypes to upload. This has to been done by yourself. In order to tell the `<InputFile />` component which files should be uploaded, you'll need to specify it for yourself.

For example:

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" class="form-control" accept="application/pdf" />
```